How to deal with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.rich.jupyter' in CLI when I want to install jupyter notebook in Windows
I want to install jupyter notebook in CLI in Windows.
I deleted some files related to jupyter notebook wrongly. When I want to install jupyter notebook in CLI again, it shows ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.rich.jupyter'.

This seems like a duplication of other posts, such as pointed out for a different post here. I believe you need to reinstall pip again. For Windows, maybe see if here seems reasonable. (Disregard anything that says pip3 at links therein. If you see pip3, just think pip. For a while people were running pip via pip3 back when Python 2 and 3 were in play.)
